# Dynamic grid remove white space

Tags: html, css, css-grid

i have created a dynamic grid. That is placing as many columns as possible. The only porblem is, that the widht need to be set. in my example i have it set to 100%.
That is generating a white space around the grid that can't befilled with a column.

is there any way to center the grid in the div or make the  width as wide as the available columns?

that my current css for the grid:

```
.card-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, calc(235px + 30px));
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    place-items: center;
    grid-auto-rows: calc(325px + 30px);
}
```

and thats the html:

```
<div className="card-grid">
    <h1>some Content</h1>
    <h1>some Content</h1>
    <h1>some Content</h1>
    <h1>some Content</h1>
    <h1>some Content</h1>
    <h1>some Content</h1>
    <h1>some Content</h1>
</div>
```

in the browser it looks like this:
[image]

And i want to remove the space that is overlapping on the right side.
Setting the width on auto doesn't work bc. then the grid has only on column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 function gridhandle(){
 var w = window.innerWidth;
 var items = document.querySelectorAll('.card-grid h1');
 var elwidth = 355;
 var itcount = items.length * elwidth > w? w / elwidth : items.length;
 var grid = document.querySelector('.card-grid');
 grid.style['grid-template-columns'] = 'repeat(' + Math.round(itcount) + ',1fr)';
 }

window.addEventListener("resize",gridhandle);
gridhandle();

</script>
```

elwidth is the width you want to set for the width of the item

```
var elwidth = 355;
```

the resize event adjusts the amount of element to display per row depending on the width of the browser

```
window.addEventListener("resize",gridhandle)
```

this script should be placed at the end of the body, after loading the dom

```
<body>
<div class="card-grid" ... >
....
</div>

  <script .... >

  ........
  </script>
</body>
```

css

```
.card-grid{
 display;grid;
 place-items:center;
 grid-auto-rows:calc(325px + 30px);
}
```

You can try with 1,2 3... the elements will always be centered

you can replace the selector

```
('.card-grid h1')
```

by

```
('.card-grid > *')
```

and you can place inside the div any type of element

Comment: If you used the snippet tool `<>` when editing, then it would be easy to for others to verify your answer.

Comment: If you have any questions regarding the code you can ask

Answer (score 0):

Try using `justify-items` and `align-itmes` separately instead of `place-items`

```
.card-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, calc(235px + 30px));
  grid-auto-rows: calc(325px + 30px);
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```